# Custom failed login error messages for users based on user role?

Tags: login, user-roles

Is there a way to give users that belong to a certain user role a unique error after failing to login?

Basically, I imported users from a site with a different CMS and it was near impossible to import their passwords. I would like to have the users of the older site belong to a specific user role to get an error saying due to the redevelopment of the website, they need to reset their passwords for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook to the `wp_login_errors` filter.

```
add_filter('wp_login_errors', function($errors, $redirect_to){

    if(isset($errors->errors['incorrect_password']) &&
    in_array('custom_role', (array) get_user_by('login', $_POST['log'])->roles)){
      $errors->errors['incorrect_password'][0] = 'Custom message';
    }

  return $errors;
}, 10, 2);
```

EDIT:

This should work with WooCommerce login form or any other form that implements `wp_signon`:

```
add_filter('authenticate', function($user, $username, $password){

    if(is_wp_error($user) && 
    isset($user->errors['incorrect_password']) &&
    in_array('custom_role', (array) get_user_by('login', $username)->roles)){
        $user->errors['incorrect_password'][0] = 'Custom message';
    }
    return $user;

}, 21, 3);
```

Comment: This works great!  Thank you so much!

Now, if I can just find the filter to hook it to the WooCommerce login form...

Comment: The second filter I added should work. @MichaelR.Burke

Comment: You're awesome, brotha!  I really should get used to messing around with filters more.

Comment: Please select my answer if it solved your issue. Glad to help :)

Comment: You got it... consider it done! :)